# Monotouch WCF Self-Hosted NetTCP Example

Tags: wcf, xamarin.ios

Can anyone point me to a WCF Self-Hosted NetTCP example that works on Monotouch?  I've searched for many hours and have come up with nothing.

I need nettcp for speed reasons (I'm transferring a lot of data between an iPad and an XP machine).  And I would much prefer self-hosting rather than using IIS to keep things simple.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoTouch does not support NetTcpBinding. MonoTouch supports the same bindings that are available in the Silverlight 3 Client Profile, which is limited to BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: This page (under the "Known issues" section) seems to indicate that NetTcpBinding is supported: http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development

Comment: MonoTouch ships with a subset of the Mono runtime. That article refers to the full Mono runtime. You do get System.ServiceModel but it only ships with BasicHttpBinding and WebHttpBinding.

Answer (score 0):

Mono WCF implementation is open source (just like the rest of Mono itself). You can, and some people do, include their own (not the MonoTouch versions) assemblies into their applications. That allows them to use some features not available in the Silverlight subset.

However this is not a simple "add source and recompile" scenario. Honestly there are many other technologies available (and well tested/supported) that could likely fit your requirements. I would have a long look at them before investing many hours into providing your own assemblies.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of other technologies I should consider?

Comment: There are many but http://www.servicestack.net/ and http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ are often cited but I have not used them personally and the level of MonoTouch compatibility will vary (e.g. not all features will be available due to lack of code generation). Anyway there's where I would start myself :-) YMMV